# Plot maximum value of a function of three variables

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, maximum

Given a function `f[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, t_]` given by

```
f[θ_, ϕ_, t_] = 
  Cos[θ]^2 Sin[t] + 
   Exp[-I ϕ] Sin[θ] Exp[-t] Sin[3 t]^2;
Plot[f[π/2, 0, t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Here, $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2 \pi$. I want a plot of $|f[\theta_0, \phi_0, t]|$ with respect to $t$ such that $\theta_0$ and $\phi_0$ make the absolute value  $|f[\theta_0, \phi_0, t]|$ maximum at that time.

Edit1: Since the function is complex. It would be necessary to talk about absolute value. I have made an edit in the question.

Edit2: I want to make my question little more precise. At every point of time say $t_1$, I want Mathematica to search over the entire allowed range of $\theta$ and $\phi$ and choose the maximum value of $|f(\theta, \phi, t_1)|$ at that time. Similarly for next time $t_2 > t_1$. Next, I need to plot those maximum values with respect to the time $t$.

Comment: Is your function complex? If so, what do you mean by ""maximum"?

Comment: @mikado, thanks for pointing out. I have made an edit.

Answer (score 5):

I might be misinterpreting the question, but it seems like the OP is asking for a 2-D representation (t vs. the maximum of f over the whole domain).

```
nmax[t_] := NMaxValue[{
   Abs[f[θ, ϕ, t]], 
   0 <= θ <= π/2 && 0 <= ϕ <= 2 π}, 
   {θ, ϕ}]

Plot[nmax[t], {t, 1, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to plot 3 variables and a value, we need some kind of 4D plotting scheme like `DensityPlot3D`.

```
f[θ_, ϕ_, t_] := Cos[θ]^2*Sin[t] + Exp[(-I)*ϕ]*Sin[θ]*Exp[-t]*Sin[3*t]^2

DensityPlot3D[
 Abs[f[θ, ϕ, t]],
 {θ, 0, π/2},
 {ϕ, 0, 2 π},
 {t, 0, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {"θ", "ϕ", "t"},
 OpacityFunction -> (# &),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Density plot of 4D function.]

I've rotated the graph a bit to better see where the function is maximized, and adjusted the opacity function a bit, although that wasn't totally necessary. It seems like $\phi$ has essentially no effect on the result. My next thought was to use `Plot3D` to look at it while ignoring $\phi$ (I'll show that graph at the end).

`Plot3D` wasn't totally necessary, but it does help me get a feel for what the function is doing in a graph that's a little easier for my mind to comprehend. I found the maximum:

```
{val, params} = 
 FindMaximum[{Abs[f[θ, ϕ, t]], 0 <= θ <= π/2, 
   0 <= ϕ <= 2 π, 0 <= t <= 10}, {θ, ϕ, t}]
```

and then used this to plot a point on the `Plot3D` that indicates where the maximum is. This is nice because I can rotate the graph around and see whether I believe it or not.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[
  Abs[f[θ, 0, t]],
  {θ, 0, π/2},
  {t, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"θ", "t", "f"},
  PlotPoints -> 200
  ],
 Graphics3D[{
   AbsolutePointSize[10],
   Point[{θ, t, val} /. params]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Plot3D of the function ignoring phi.]

Once you run the code, you can rotate the `Plot3D` and see if you believe the result. Of course, I've ignored $\phi$ for the purposes of this final plot because it didn't look to my eye like it had much effect, but the `FindMaximum` algorithm does take it into account. Over a constrained area that doesn't appear to have any super unusual features, I expect that `FindMaximum` should do a very good job of finding the true global maximum.

Comment: I don't think that it is a 4D-problem. For given t there is a maximum `{\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t], t}` which can be plotted in 3D.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Ah, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ MassDefect But you gave an interesting solution approach!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
max[t_] := {\[Theta], \[Phi], t} /. NMaximize [{Conjugate[f[\[Theta], \[Phi], t]] f[\[Theta], \[Phi], t], 0 < \[Theta] < Pi/2, 0 < \[Phi] < 2 Pi}, {\[Theta], \[Phi]}][[2]]
```

to find the maximum `{\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t], t}` for given t:

```
max[1]
(* {0.135214, 1.79353, 1} *)
```

I don't know why `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[max[t]], {t, 0, 1}]` doesn't work, but you can plot the maxima as follows

```
pt = Table[max[t], {t, 0, 10, .1}];
Graphics3D[{Point[pt]}, BoxRatios -> {Pi/2, 2 Pi, 10}]
```

[image]